# Python socketio badnamespaceerror exception on one device but not working on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-socketio

Hi all I have the following code but for some reason I keep getting the following error but it seems to work on a colleagues pc. We can't seem to figure out why this won't work on mine.

We have also double checked that we're importing the same socketio using dir()

I've tried specifying the namespace both on sio.connect and in the sio.emit but still no luck!

`socketio.exceptions.BadNamespaceError: / is not a connected namespace.`

```
bearerToken = 'REDACT'

core = 'REDACT'
output = 'REDACT'


import socketio
import json

def getListeners(token, coreUrl, outputId):
    sio = socketio.Client(reconnection_attempts=5, request_timeout=5)
    sio.connect(url=coreUrl, transports='websocket')

    @sio.on('mwedge:batch:stats')
    def batchStats(data):
        if (outputId in data['outputStats']):
            listeners = data['outputStats'][outputId][16]
            print("Number of listeners ", len(listeners))
            ips = []
            for listener in listeners:
                ips.append(listener[1])
            print("Ips", ips)

    def authCallback(data):
        print(json.dumps(data))

    sio.emit(event='auth',
    data={
        'token': token
    },
    callback=authCallback)


getListeners(bearerToken, core, output)
```

Answer (score 5):

The Socket.IO connection involves a number of exchanges between the client and the server. The `connect()` function initiates this process, but this continues in the background. The connection ends when the handler for your `connect` event is invoked. At this point you can emit.

The problem with your code is that you are not waiting until the connection handshakes are completed, so your `emit()` call happens before there is a connection established. The solution is to add a `connect` event handler, and move your `emit()` call there.

As an additional note, I suggest you set up your event handlers before you call the `connect()` function.